# Orchard CMS Migrations and Taxonomies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I'm creating a new part that needs a taxonomy to be attached.

It is easy to attach a taxonomy field in migration:

```
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("RecipePart", part => part
    .WithField("Categoria", cfg => cfg
        .OfType("TaxonomyField")
        .WithSetting("TaxonomyFieldSettings.AllowCustomTerms", "false")
        .WithSetting("TaxonomyFieldSettings.SingleChoice", "false")
        .WithSetting("TaxonomyFieldSettings.LeavesOnly", "true")
        .WithSetting("TaxonomyFieldSettings.Required", "true")
        .WithSetting("TaxonomyFieldSettings.Taxonomy", "Ricette Categorie"))
    .WithDescription("Categorie ricette."));
```

But... I need to manually create the Taxonomy and the related terms.

Is it possible to check is Taxonomy exists (eg. "Ricette Categorie" in this sample case)  and, if not found, add one with some default terms so that part is ready to use without manual intervention?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
var itemTypeTaxonomy = _taxonomyService.GetTaxonomyByName("ItemType");
if (itemTypeTaxonomy == null)
{
    itemTypeTaxonomy = _orchardServices.ContentManager.New("Taxonomy").As<TaxonomyPart>();
    itemTypeTaxonomy.Name = "ItemType";
    itemTypeTaxonomy.ContentItem.As<TitlePart>().Title = "ItemType";
    _taxonomyService.CreateTermContentType(itemTypeTaxonomy);
    _orchardServices.ContentManager.Create(itemTypeTaxonomy);
    _orchardServices.ContentManager.Publish(itemTypeTaxonomy.ContentItem);
}

ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("StandardItemPart", cfg => cfg
    .WithField("Description", field => field.OfType("HtmlField"))
    .WithField("Thumbnail", field => field.OfType("MediaPickerField"))
    .WithField("Length", field => field.OfType("TextField"))
    .WithField("Type", field => field.OfType("TaxonomyField").WithSetting("FieldIndexing.Included", "True")
                                                               .WithSetting("TaxonomyFieldSettings.TaxonomyId", itemTypeTaxonomy.Id.ToString())
                                                               .WithSetting("TaxonomyFieldSettings.LeavesOnly", "True")
                                                               .WithSetting("TaxonomyFieldSettings.SingleChoice", "True")));
```

This is for the old taxonomies module when RoutePart still existed, which has now been replaced by AutoroutePart but the idea is there

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Hazza to point me in the right direction...

I ended up to this code that creates the Taxonomy and adds the terms if they not exists:

```
    private void CreateTaxonomy(string taxonomyName, string[] terms)
    {
        var taxonomy = _taxonomyService.GetTaxonomyByName(taxonomyName);

        if (taxonomy == null)
        {
            taxonomy = _orchardServices.ContentManager.New("Taxonomy").As<TaxonomyPart>();
            taxonomy.Name = taxonomyName;
            taxonomy.ContentItem.As<TitlePart>().Title = taxonomyName;
            _taxonomyService.CreateTermContentType(taxonomy);
            _orchardServices.ContentManager.Create(taxonomy);
            _orchardServices.ContentManager.Publish(taxonomy.ContentItem);
        }

        foreach (var term in terms)
        {
            GetOrCreateTerm(taxonomy.Id, term);
        }
    }
```

the GetOrCreateTerm is a private method I have created after the original one on Orchard Source (TaxonomyFieldDriver.cs)

Answer (score 0):

Below is code to create Taxonomy and terms

```
public void Enabled(Feature feature) {
    if (_taxonomyService.GetTaxonomyByName("Genre") == null) {


        var tax = _contentManager.New<TaxonomyPart>("Taxonomy");
        tax.Name = "Genre";
        _contentManager.Create(tax, VersionOptions.Published);

        CreateTerm(tax, "Action");
        CreateTerm(tax, "Comedy");
        CreateTerm(tax, "Drama");
        CreateTerm(tax, "Panaorama");
        CreateTerm(tax, "Shikorama");
    }

}

private void CreateTerm(TaxonomyPart tax, string termName) {
    var term = _taxonomyService.NewTerm(tax);
    term.Name = termName;
    _contentManager.Create(term, VersionOptions.Published);
}
```

I added this code to the FeatureEventHandler class of my module, So that it runs when I enable the feature.